# How can I turn ON the "new email" envelope overlay that appears on top of the dock icon in Outlook 2016 for Mac?

Tags: mac, email, microsoft-outlook-2016

Since updating outlook to 15.29 for mac, there is no longer any indicator on the outlook icon on the dock to let me know I have new email. I went into notification preferences, and got it to bounce when something new comes in (not much help), but need a visual indicator that tells me I have email, and stays on until I open the program. Any suggestions? Many thanks!

Comment: I think I ran into the same thing. If this is the same issue I ran into, the "new mail" icon has (or used to have) a white envelope in front of the Outlook logo when there are new emails since the last time Outlook had the focus of OS X, right? For potential answerers, this isn't the same as the "unread" badge on the icon.